# Is there alternate for dom event listeners in express js

Tags: express, ejs

since express js doesn't allow Dom related commands, so I am not able to keep tracks of buttons i.e. when they are clicked. Not just button clicking but any kind of tracking is not possible. Can anyone please suggest a alternate for this. If there is nothing in express, a new library or anything that can work with express and help me with this. Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest doing a little reading on the client/server architecture that Express+web browser represent.  It is absolutely required that you understand what code runs on your server and what code runs on the end-user's computer in their browser.  Without that base level of understanding, developing any sort of custom web app is going to be very, very confusing.

Comment: sure will do that. @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing things here. Express.js runs on the backend. There is no DOM on the backend, hence there is no API to manipulate the DOM.

You can use template engines (express supports e.g. [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and [EJS](https://ejs.co/)) and link JavaScript files within the HTML that you return. Or you use a frontend framework like React, Vue, Svelte, Angular etc. in order to do this.

Comment: Hey @Mushroomator , tnx for the answer. I am very new to this. I can track those with ejs as you mentioned, but then how can I send the received data to express main file like in this example info abt button pressing. Those are two entirely different files. ty

Comment: Hey @mushroomator, I read about extracting data using fetch api. So apart from server.js running, I am using additional javascript which is using event listeners to track button clicks. I am storing those clicks info in a nested list. So one way I see is adding them to sql from there. then using them in server backend by getting from sql again. I am not getting on how can I use fetchapi for list or any local containers, over local server. Can you please please suggest anything. Any help is great. ty

Comment: I suggest you start to look at a Fullstack Tutorial Playlist like [this](https://youtu.be/l3DLiZgd184) (this has 8 parts an builds a simple application) on YouTube. They will explain everything required to make Frontend, Backend, the Database and deployment work.